# Can I resolve dependencies of maven artifacts in artifactory?

Tags: maven, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

We are currently migrating from Nexus to Artifactory and one thing we are missing is an API call to resolve maven dependencies in artifactory. Nexus has this endpoint `/service/local/dependency?r=snapshots,releases&c=&e=pom&s=compile&f=list&g=<my.group>&a=<my-artifact>&v=<my-version>` which gives a compiled list of all, including transitive, depdendencies.

We need this because we (mis)use maven as a generic deployment/versioning system to create artifacts (zip files of shell scripts actually) and to manage depenedencies. These dependencies are also necessary for production deployments.

Since we migrate from Nexus we don't have builds accessible and I am not yet sure if we want to use them. Is there a way to get a rest endpoint like the nexus one in Artifactory? Maybe a user plugin? Any hints on how this could be done?